# Replacing 10" Kobalt sliding miter saw blade

Tags: repair, replacement, saw, miter

Years ago I bought a Kobalt sliding miter saw (10") and have never changed the blade. I have lost the instructions manual and Google hasn't been much help. I am trying to figure out how to take the old blade off and posted [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_uFfNV4MWnU) detailing exactly where I'm going awry.

But essentially I have removed some of the protective fencing around the blade, as well as the bolt that goes through the hole in the center of the blade. Now I am trying to remove what I *believe* is called the *arbor* but I am unsure of this name. Its a (approx) 2" metal disc that appears to be securing the blade to the motor housing.

Can anyone help me figure out how to remove this arbor, or whatever it is, to get the blade off? Also I have a replacement blade that is also 10" with and appropriate sized arbor (5/8"), but it is a **DeWalt** blade -- compatible, or not at all?

Thanks for any and all help here!

Comment: Years ago usually means you need to use a rubber mallet to help the arbor/blade to come loose.  Name on the blade usually only matters how much you pay for it.

Comment: if you removed the bolt in the center of the blade and it still won't come off, it's **stuck**, simple as that! bang on it with a large rubber mallet or stout piece of wood and you might be able to bust it free.   Some penetrating oil applied to the arbor hole might help.

Comment: The "arbor" is the threaded screw that comes out of the motor housing, over which the blade slides, followed by the washer then the "arbor nut". Sounds like you've got the arbor nut off. The 2" disk is the washer. Follow Ecnerwal's advice to tap the blade to get it to break loose.

Comment: What is your saw model number? closest I can get without a model number is this, which has a slightly involved procedure due to the blade guard. But still no need to remove the guard. https://manualsfile.com/product/p3pq6ykr4v.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't remove the arbor from the saw to change the blade. You remove the blade from the arbor. After 10 years it may be pretty well stuck, but normally it can be convinced to move by tapping around the edge of the blade, rotating it by hand.

With a blade you might ever want to use again that needs to be pretty carefully done with something soft. With a 10 year old blade, less care is required as you're unlikely to install it ever again, but you still don't want to hit so hard as to damage the saw, rather than the used-up blade.

You should not normally need to remove anything but the blade securing bolt, and a washer (which will come off with the blade if it's somewhat stuck from old age) to change a blade on most saws.

Comment: Thanks guys, this was all I needed to do; mallet worked it out perfectly fine and I'm good to go -- thanks!